# RSpec stubbing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to stub a method in a REST client, but the method isn't being stubbed and always
makes a call to the server. I would like to know why `get_additional_info` is not being stubbed.

**Spec**

```
describe "Test Controller" do
  it "will update and redirect to contract" do
    RestClientWrapper.any_instance.stub(:get_additional_info).and_return(AdditionalInfo.new({required_info: "..."}))
    put :update, {id: 1, bank: {}}, session_user
    should redirect_to contract_path
  end
```

end

**Controller**

```
def update
   additional_info = MyCompany::api.get_additional_info(auth_token,decision.id)
end
```

**MyCompany.rb**

```
def self.api
   RestClientWrapper.new
end
```

Comment: Your update action seems to be incomplete. How do you initialize `rest_client_wrapper` object?

Comment: There is other code in update, I removed it to make things concise. rest_client_wrapper has already been initialized.

Comment: It would be good to show us the initialization part of `rest_client_wrapper`. Or post what you get when you print `rest_client_wrapper.class`

Comment: updated with more details

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why what you have doesn't work. But try this

```
MyCompany.stub(:api).and_return(mock("rest_client_wrapper", :get_additional_info => AdditionalInfo.new({required_info: "..."})))
```